# SQL Server Pivot with Multiple Rows Output

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following data in a Table.

[image]

And i need output in below format.

[image]

I tried pivoting but seems like not able to resolve it.
Can someone please guide me here?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Data in Text Format.

| EmployeeID | ShiftCode | AttendanceDate | inDateTime | outDateTime | OverTimeHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 01-03-2022 | 01-03-2022 09:10 | 01-03-2022 18:10 | 1 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 02-03-2022 | 02-03-2022 09:15 | 02-03-2022 18:15 | 2 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 03-03-2022 | 03-03-2022 09:05 | 03-03-2022 18:05 | 2 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 04-03-2022 | 04-03-2022 09:10 | 04-03-2022 18:10 | 1 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 05-03-2022 | 05-03-2022 09:13 | 05-03-2022 18:13 | 2 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 06-03-2022 | 06-03-2022 09:14 | 06-03-2022 18:14 | 3 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 07-03-2022 | 07-03-2022 09:16 | 07-03-2022 18:16 | 2 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 08-03-2022 | 08-03-2022 09:30 | 08-03-2022 18:30 | 1 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 09-03-2022 | 09-03-2022 09:20 | 09-03-2022 18:20 | 2 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | 10-03-2022 | 10-03-2022 09:25 | 10-03-2022 18:25 | 3 |

output in Text Format:

| EmployeeID | ShiftCode | DataType | 01-03-2022 | 02-03-2022 | 03-03-2022 | 04-03-2022 | 05-03-2022 | 06-03-2022 | 07-03-2022 | 08-03-2022 | 09-03-2022 | 10-03-2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | InDateTime | 01-03-2022 09:10 | 02-03-2022 09:15 | 03-03-2022 09:05 | 04-03-2022 09:10 | 05-03-2022 09:13 | 06-03-2022 09:14 | 07-03-2022 09:16 | 08-03-2022 09:30 | 09-03-2022 09:20 | 10-03-2022 09:25 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | OutDateTime | 01-03-2022 18:10 | 02-03-2022 18:15 | 03-03-2022 18:05 | 04-03-2022 18:10 | 05-03-2022 18:13 | 06-03-2022 18:14 | 07-03-2022 18:16 | 08-03-2022 18:30 | 09-03-2022 18:20 | 10-03-2022 18:25 |
| 26 | ShiftCC1 | OverTimeHours | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: Could you provide your data in text format?

Comment: Hi @UmutTEKİN - Data in text Format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can' t have the exactly output you want with your dataset. Either you need to give up your overtime column because after pivotting those columns automatically convert to date type or you could change datatype of your columns(I used view for that).

Also, I assumed your "AttendanceDate" is dynamic, so I used a dynamic solution.

[I used @Taryn' s solution here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Option 1:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.att_date) 
            FROM test1 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT idx, name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select idx,
                       name,
                    att_date,
                    att_entry
                from test1
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(att_entry)
                for att_date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            union 
            SELECT idx, name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select idx,
                       name,
                    att_date,
                    att_out
                from test1
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(att_out)
                for att_date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

[image]

[DBFiddle_Option1:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=63569bfee8a2e3426b40b9d73594d087)

or

Option2:

You can create a view like this to bypass column incompatibility.

```
create view test2
as select idx, name as name, convert(varchar, att_date) as att_date,
convert(varchar, att_entry) as att_entry,
convert(varchar, att_out) as att_out,
convert(varchar, overtime) as overtime
from test1;
```

Then you can use this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.att_date) 
            FROM test2 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT idx, name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select idx,
                       name,
                    att_date,
                    overtime
                from test2
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(overtime)
                for att_date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            union 
            SELECT idx, name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select idx,
                       name,
                    att_date,
                    att_out
                from test2
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(att_out)
                for att_date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            union 
            SELECT idx, name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select idx,
                       name,
                    att_date,
                    att_entry
                from test2
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(att_entry)
                for att_date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p order by 3 desc'

execute(@query)
```

[image]

[DBFiddle_Option2:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6797a2b6c74001c231c731b768f110dc)

Note: without converting data to string it looks like this at the end:

[image]

Comment: I understand that it is not the most optimized way but it solves my problem. Thanks a Lot.